# WooCommerce: Get current shipping address in checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

I added a couple of extra fields to my billing and shipping addresses. One of them is a discount, which can only be added by an admin (hidden from everyone else). Different shipping addresses have different discounts (I'm using a plunging that saves multiple addresses per customer).

During checkout, I want to load the discount for that shipping address. I’m calling a method via ajax (there are other fields that also update the shipping method and payment gateway when changed), which works fine. For those fields, I just pass their value via JS to the PHP by grabbing them from the form. I can’t do that for a discount, as someone may just open developer tools and manually change the discount. I need to grab it from the DB.

In that method that gets called when the card first loads, I’ve tried to get the address as follows:

`WC()->order->get_address('shipping')`;

But I get an error as if the method doesn’t exist.

`And WC()->order` returns empty.

I loaded `WC()->customer` and I can see it there, but it’s buried in some pretty deep nested objects and arrays which you can tell would change from customer to customer. And `WC()->session` has only the default address fields (not my custom fields).

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you tried `WC()->customer->get_shipping_address();` ?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that since I'm using a multiple address plugin, I need to know which address is being picked. I found a solution by sending via ajax the current address picked in the checkout form, and with that address check the customer meta to find the correct one with the respective discount.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was check 3 addresses in the cart and then loaded the customer meta and checked for an address that matched (I found the key used to store the extra address in meta), and then grabbed the discount from that address:

```php
$discount = null;
$address1 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_1();
$address2 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2();
$addressCity = WC()->customer->get_shipping_city();
$c = WC()->customer->get_meta('thwma_custom_address');
if (is_array($c)) {
    foreach ($c as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "shipping") {
            foreach ($val as $v) {
                if (isset($v['dealer_discount']) && $v['shipping_address_1'] == esc_html($address1) && $v['shipping_address_2'] == esc_html($address2) && $v['shipping_city'] == esc_html($addressCity)) {
                    $discount = absint($v['dealer_discount']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```